# How do I analytically transform Wishart to inverse-Wishart?

Tags: probability, bayesian, density-function

How do I transform the probability density function of the Wishart distribution into that of the inverse-Wishart distribution? I'd like to know the whole process.

Comment: You might get better luck with a 'probability' tag or something like that. This is not necessarily Bayesian.

Comment: You might get better luck if you specified how you are defining an inverse-Wishart distribution, as the term inverse has several competing common definitions.